# Algebraic form to code

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming

I have a homework where we are supposed to implement a functional datatype for any generic datatype. The specifications for the class are given in algebraic form. I'm having problems interpreting it and would like some help.

Here are the specifications that we got in algebraic form:

T is any generic datatype

> **Values** V = {nil} ∪ T
>
> **Expressions** E = {(cons e1 e2) ∣ e1, e2 ∈ E} ∪ V
>   Let L^n ⊂ E contain only expressions of the form (cons e1 (cons e2 . . . (cons en nil) . . .)
>   with all ei ∈ T for some n ∈ N. Let further L^∗ = ⋃n∈N L^n.
>
> **Functions**
>
> **empty?** ∶ E → {true,false}, e ↦ {true if e = nil, false otherwise
>
> **first** ∶ L^∗ → E, (cons e1 e2) ↦ e1
>
> **rest ∶** L^∗ → E, (cons e1 e2) ↦ e2
>
> **prepend** ∶ E × L^∗ → L^∗, e, (cons e1 e2) ↦ (cons e (cons e1 e2))
>
> **ith** ∶ (L^∗)×N → E, (cons e1 . . . (cons ei. . . (cons en nil) . . .), i ↦ ei for 0 < i ≤ n
>
> **length** ∶ L^∗ → N,l ∈ L^n ↦ n

Here are my interpretations:

**Values:** The values are of the class T and are nil(null)

**Expressions:**

Not sure if E is an array that consists of constants e1,e2... and that L^n is also an array that consists of e1,e2... en? Don't understand the (cons en nil) part... are the constants supposed to be nil?

**Functions**

**Empty?** function empty is supposed to check an element in the E array has a value or not.

**first:** returns first element

**rest:** returns a new array without the first element

**prepend:** puts the constant e first in the array.

**ith:** Not sure, maybe return n elements depending on input.

**length**: give length of the list L

The expressions are a bit messy but could anyone give me some feedback on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `T` be `int`. Then `V` is any int or a nul. Now, expressions can be `cons(x y)` where `x,y` are either ints or nuls or other expressions, for example:

```
1
cons(2 3)
cons(cons(4 5) cons(6 7))
```

`L^n` is a special kind of expression where the first argument of `cons` is limited to be `T` and the innermost atom must be nul. So this

```
cons(1 cons(2 cons(3 nul)))
```

is a valid `L^n` (specifically `L^3`), while this is not

```
cons(cons(4 5) cons(6 7))
```

(as a side note, `L^n` is what's called `list` in lisp, while `E` is a generic `pair`).

From your set of functions, only `empty?` (aka `nil`), `first` (=car) and `rest` (=cdr) are primitive, others can be defined in terms of them (provided you've also got the conditional), for example:

```
 length(E) = 0 if empty(E) else 1 + length(rest(E))
```

Comment: So in java, E could a class called cons that hold a pair of x,y? And L^n is a list that holds the pairs where the last value must be nul?

Comment: Or I think what you mean now... L^n is supposed to be used "recursively"? If i have my class cons(x,y) then I can define L^3 by doing: L3=cons(1,cons(2,cons(3,nul)) (java code)

Comment: Yes, the definition of `L^n` is recursive. Basically, you're challenged to write a subset of Lisp in java.